# AppIndicator vala library

Tags: indicator, vala

I want to make an tasks indicator app for google apps in vala. But i can't seem to find the appindicator library i need to make this. 
I'm relatively new to vala but i can't find the vapi file, so I can't compile my programs...

Here is an example of a vala appindicator
http://developer.ubuntu.com/resources/technologies/application-indicators/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The VAPI is in the [libappindicator-dev](http://packages.ubuntu.com/quantal/libappindicator-dev) package.