# Gnome3 AppIndicator Vala app cannot show submenu (it auto-closes immediately)?

Tags: gnome, 18.04, vala

Consider the source code, pasted below as `test.vala`. It is a simple application which should show an icon on top bar/panel, when the icon is clicked it should show a menu with one item in it (Open), when you click on Open it should show a submenu with several items in it. I compile this on:

```
$ cat /etc/issue
Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS \n \l
$ uname -a
Linux MyPC 4.15.0-38-generic #41-Ubuntu SMP Wed Oct 10 10:59:38 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
$ printf 'Desktop: %s\nSession: %s\n' "$XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP" "$GDMSESSION"
Desktop: ubuntu:GNOME
Session: ubuntu
$ gnome-shell --version
GNOME Shell 3.28.3
```

... and I compile with:

```
valac -X -D'GETTEXT_PACKAGE="my-indicator"' -D NEWMETHOD --pkg=gtk+-3.0 --pkg appindicator3-0.1 test.vala
```

... and for this you'll also need to install [the libappindicator-dev package](https://askubuntu.com/questions/253416/appindicator-vala-library).

Then I run the application:

```
$ ./test 
main() ... 
Main(): ok
Creating MainWindow
^C
```

... and the result I get is shown on this animated gif:

[image: out.gif]

Note that appindicator icon is shown (as expected), upon clicking it the first-level menu with the "Open" item is shown (as expected) - but when I click on "Open", I don't really get the submenu that I expect; instead it looks like there is an attempt to open the submenu, and it closes immediately?

What do I need to do, so that this app opens the submenu properly?

Here is `test.vala`:

```
// build with:
// valac -X -D'GETTEXT_PACKAGE="my-indicator"' --pkg=gtk+-3.0 --pkg appindicator3-0.1 test.vala

// "It's not possible to define a preprocessor symbol inside the Vala code (like with C). The only way to define a symbol is to feed it through the valac option -D."
// valac -X -D'GETTEXT_PACKAGE="my-indicator"' -D NEWMETHOD --pkg=gtk+-3.0 --pkg appindicator3-0.1 test.vala

// see also: https://valadoc.org/gtk+-3.0/Gtk.MenuItem.html

using GLib;
using Gtk;
using AppIndicator;

public Main App;
public const string AppName = "Test";

extern void exit(int exit_code);

public class MyIndicator: GLib.Object{

  protected Indicator indicator;
  protected string icon;
  protected string name;

  public MyIndicator(){

    App.my_indicator = this;

    this.name = "My Indicator";

    this.icon = "account-logged-in"; // looks like a checkmark
    this.indicator = new Indicator("my_indicator", icon, IndicatorCategory.APPLICATION_STATUS);
    indicator.set_status(IndicatorStatus.ACTIVE);

    var menu = new Gtk.Menu();

    // open -------------------------------------
    #if NEWMETHOD
      var item = new Gtk.MenuItem.with_label(_("Open"));
    #else
      var item = new Gtk.ImageMenuItem.with_label(_("Open"));
    #endif
    menu.append(item);
    var item_open = item;

    item.set_reserve_indicator(false);

    item.activate.connect(() => {
      var submenu = new Gtk.Menu();
      submenu.reserve_toggle_size = true;
      //var dummy_window = new Gtk.Window();
      //Gtk.Image icon = null;
      int i;
      for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        #if NEWMETHOD
          var subitem = new Gtk.MenuItem.with_label ( "Exit %d".printf(i) );
        #else
          var subitem = new Gtk.ImageMenuItem.with_label ( "Exit %d".printf(i) );
        #endif
        subitem.set_reserve_indicator(true);
        submenu.append(subitem);
        subitem.activate.connect(() => {
          App.exit_app();
          exit(0);
        });
        //subitem.activate();
      }
      submenu.show_all();

      item_open.set_submenu(submenu);
    });
    item.activate(); // so it shows submenu triangle

    indicator.set_menu(menu);
    menu.show_all();
  }
}


public class Main : GLib.Object{

  public MyIndicator my_indicator;

  public static int main (string[] args) {

    stdout.printf("main() ... \n");
    stdout.flush();
    Gtk.init(ref args);
    App = new Main(args);
    bool success = App.start_application(args);
    App.exit_app();

    return (success) ? 0 : 1;
  }

  public Main(string[] args){
    stdout.printf("Main(): ok\n");
    stdout.flush();
  }

  public bool start_application(string[] args){
    stdout.printf("Creating MainWindow\n");
    stdout.flush();

    new MyIndicator(); // var ind = new MyIndicator();

    //start event loop
    Gtk.main();

    return true;
  }

  public void exit_app (){
    stdout.printf("exit_app()\n");
    stdout.flush();
    Gtk.main_quit ();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT: see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53805975/re-creating-gtk-menu-in-event-handler-with-vala

---

Ok, got it - rewrote the above code so the submenu creation is a separate function, so it got easier to identify that the problem was here:

```
item_open.activate.connect(() => {
  //~ item_open.set_submenu(createSubmenu()); // NO; having the set_submenu run in .connect, causes immediate shutdown of the created submenu!!
  stdout.printf("item.activate.connect running\n");
});
item_open.set_submenu(createSubmenu()); // is OK here
item_open.activate(); // so it shows submenu triangle
```

As the comment says,  having the `set_submenu` run in `.connect,` causes immediate shutdown of the created submenu. I guess that is because inside the `.connect` handler, we have some "anonymous context" or whatever, which causes all local variables created there to be destroyed when the handler exits, regardless of if any of those are referenced elsewhere or not. So the solution is to run the `createSubmenu` outside of the connect handler.

Note that, even with this working code, when compiling it I get:

```
$ valac -X -D'GETTEXT_PACKAGE="my-indicator"' -D NEWMETHOD --pkg=gtk+-3.0 --pkg appindicator3-0.1 test.vala
/tmp/test.vala.c: In function ‘my_indicator_createSubmenu’:
/tmp/test.vala.c:182:52: warning: passing argument 2 of ‘gtk_menu_shell_append’ from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
    gtk_menu_shell_append ((GtkMenuShell*) _tmp11_, _tmp12_);
                                                    ^~~~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/gtk-3.0/gtk/gtkmenu.h:33:0,
                 from /usr/include/gtk-3.0/gtk/gtklabel.h:34,
                 from /usr/include/gtk-3.0/gtk/gtkaccellabel.h:35,
                 from /usr/include/gtk-3.0/gtk/gtk.h:33,
                 from /usr/include/libappindicator3-0.1/libappindicator/app-indicator.h:33,
                 from /tmp/test.vala.c:15:
/usr/include/gtk-3.0/gtk/gtkmenushell.h:91:10: note: expected ‘GtkWidget * {aka struct _GtkWidget *}’ but argument is of type ‘GtkMenuItem * {aka struct _GtkMenuItem *}’
 void     gtk_menu_shell_append         (GtkMenuShell *menu_shell,
          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/tmp/test.vala.c: In function ‘my_indicator_construct’:
/tmp/test.vala.c:260:47: warning: passing argument 2 of ‘gtk_menu_shell_append’ from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
  gtk_menu_shell_append ((GtkMenuShell*) menu, item_open);
                                               ^~~~~~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/gtk-3.0/gtk/gtkmenu.h:33:0,
                 from /usr/include/gtk-3.0/gtk/gtklabel.h:34,
                 from /usr/include/gtk-3.0/gtk/gtkaccellabel.h:35,
                 from /usr/include/gtk-3.0/gtk/gtk.h:33,
                 from /usr/include/libappindicator3-0.1/libappindicator/app-indicator.h:33,
                 from /tmp/test.vala.c:15:
/usr/include/gtk-3.0/gtk/gtkmenushell.h:91:10: note: expected ‘GtkWidget * {aka struct _GtkWidget *}’ but argument is of type ‘GtkMenuItem * {aka struct _GtkMenuItem *}’
 void     gtk_menu_shell_append         (GtkMenuShell *menu_shell,
          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/tmp/test.vala.c:265:40: warning: passing argument 2 of ‘gtk_menu_item_set_submenu’ from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
  gtk_menu_item_set_submenu (item_open, _tmp10_);
                                        ^~~~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/gtk-3.0/gtk/gtkcheckmenuitem.h:33:0,
                 from /usr/include/gtk-3.0/gtk/gtk.h:72,
                 from /usr/include/libappindicator3-0.1/libappindicator/app-indicator.h:33,
                 from /tmp/test.vala.c:15:
/usr/include/gtk-3.0/gtk/gtkmenuitem.h:120:12: note: expected ‘GtkWidget * {aka struct _GtkWidget *}’ but argument is of type ‘GtkMenu * {aka struct _GtkMenu *}’
 void       gtk_menu_item_set_submenu          (GtkMenuItem         *menu_item,
            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

... but I guess it is not that big of a problem. Probably libappindicator3 needs to be changed.

Anyways, here is the full updated (and working) code of `test.vala`:

```
// build with:
// valac -X -D'GETTEXT_PACKAGE="my-indicator"' --pkg=gtk+-3.0 --pkg appindicator3-0.1 test.vala

// "It's not possible to define a preprocessor symbol inside the Vala code (like with C). The only way to define a symbol is to feed it through the valac option -D."
// valac -X -D'GETTEXT_PACKAGE="my-indicator"' -D NEWMETHOD --pkg=gtk+-3.0 --pkg appindicator3-0.1 test.vala

// see also: https://valadoc.org/gtk+-3.0/Gtk.MenuItem.html

using GLib;
using Gtk;
using AppIndicator;

public Main App;
public const string AppName = "Test";

extern void exit(int exit_code);

public class MyIndicator: GLib.Object{

  protected Indicator indicator;
  protected string icon;
  protected string name;

  public Gtk.Menu createSubmenu(){
    var submenu = new Gtk.Menu();
    submenu.reserve_toggle_size = true;
    //var dummy_window = new Gtk.Window();
    //Gtk.Image icon = null;
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
      #if NEWMETHOD
        var subitem = new Gtk.MenuItem.with_label ( "Exit %d".printf(i) );
      #else
        var subitem = new Gtk.ImageMenuItem.with_label ( "Exit %d".printf(i) );
      #endif

      subitem.set_reserve_indicator(true);
      submenu.append(subitem);
      subitem.activate.connect(() => {
        App.exit_app();
        exit(0);
      });
      //subitem.activate(); // no way, causes immediate exit!
    }

    submenu.show_all();
    return submenu;
  }
  public MyIndicator(){

    App.my_indicator = this;

    this.name = "My Indicator";

    this.icon = "account-logged-in"; // looks like a checkmark
    this.indicator = new Indicator("my_indicator", icon, IndicatorCategory.APPLICATION_STATUS);
    indicator.set_status(IndicatorStatus.ACTIVE);

    /*
    // from https://valadoc.org/gtk+-3.0/Gtk.Menu.html
        // MenuBar:
        //Gtk.MenuBar bar = new Gtk.MenuBar (); //error: Argument 1: Cannot convert from `unowned Gtk.MenuBar?' to `unowned Gtk.Menu?'
        Gtk.Menu bar = new Gtk.Menu ();
        //indicator.add (bar); // error: The name `add' does not exist in the context of `AppIndicator.Indicator'
    indicator.set_menu(bar);

        // File:
        Gtk.MenuItem item_file = new Gtk.MenuItem.with_label ("File");
        bar.add (item_file);

        Gtk.Menu filemenu = new Gtk.Menu ();
        item_file.set_submenu (filemenu);

        Gtk.MenuItem item_open = new Gtk.MenuItem.with_label ("Open");
        filemenu.add (item_open);

        // Submenu:
        Gtk.Menu submenu = new Gtk.Menu ();
        item_open.set_submenu (submenu);

        Gtk.MenuItem item_foo = new Gtk.MenuItem.with_label ("foo");
        submenu.add (item_foo);

        Gtk.MenuItem item_bar = new Gtk.MenuItem.with_label ("bar");
        submenu.add (item_bar);

    bar.show_all();
    */

    var menu = new Gtk.Menu();

    // open -------------------------------------
    #if NEWMETHOD
      var item_open = new Gtk.MenuItem.with_label(_("Open"));
    #else
      var item_open = new Gtk.ImageMenuItem.with_label(_("Open"));
    #endif
    menu.append(item_open);

    item_open.set_reserve_indicator(false);

    item_open.activate.connect(() => {
      //~ item_open.set_submenu(createSubmenu()); // NO; having the set_submenu run in .connect, causes immediate shutdown of the created submenu!!
      stdout.printf("item.activate.connect running\n");
    });
    item_open.set_submenu(createSubmenu()); // is OK here
    item_open.activate(); // so it shows submenu triangle

    indicator.set_menu(menu);
    menu.show_all();
  }
}


public class Main : GLib.Object{

  public MyIndicator my_indicator;

  public static int main (string[] args) {

    stdout.printf("main() ... \n");
    stdout.flush();
    Gtk.init(ref args);
    App = new Main(args);
    bool success = App.start_application(args);
    App.exit_app();

    return (success) ? 0 : 1;
  }

  public Main(string[] args){
    stdout.printf("Main(): ok\n");
    stdout.flush();
  }

  public bool start_application(string[] args){
    stdout.printf("Creating MainWindow\n");
    stdout.flush();

    new MyIndicator(); // var ind = new MyIndicator();

    //start event loop
    Gtk.main();

    return true;
  }

  public void exit_app (){
    stdout.printf("exit_app()\n");
    stdout.flush();
    Gtk.main_quit ();
  }
}
```